# mysql custom wp query

Tags: functions, query-posts, mysql

this code is designed to select posts with selected meta value in wordpress query

```
<?php $values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key  = 'wpcf-scr'",ARRAY_A);?>
<select name="wpcf-scr">
<option value="">default</option>
<?php foreach ($values as $value):?>
<?php if($value['meta_value']):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value['meta_value']?>"><?php echo $value['meta_value']?></option>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

I need to re use the code but with selecting posts with tags(manual assigned) not meta values...

something like this below just for explanation (it's wrong)

```
<?php $values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_tags FROM $wpdb->tags ",ARRAY_A);?>
<select name="tags">
<option value="">default</option>
<option value="tag1">tag1</option>
<option value="tag1">tag2</option>
<option value="tag1">tag3</option>
<option value="tag1">tag4</option>
</select>
```

How to make the second example correctly ?

thanks

Comment: Note that what you're looking for is `post_tag` not `post_tags`.

Answer (score 1):

It'll never work, as there is no `tags` table in a default WP database (nor a post_tags column for that matter). For that query to work, you'd have to look within and join `term_relationships`, `term_taxonomy` and `terms` tables. Complicated stuff.

If you're not familiar with MySQL queries or WP's database structure, just use the [get_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) function instead. You don't even have to provide any arguments: it will return all the existing post tags as an array of objects. Here's an example, based on your question's code:

```
<?php
$values = get_tags();
if(sizeof($values) > 0) : ?>
    <select name="tags">
        <option value="">default</option>
    <?php
        // I've used value=id instead of name / slug, which is always better, but just change the index if desired
        foreach ($values as $value) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo($value->term_id); ?>"><?php echo($value->name); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function and pass `post_tag` as `taxonomy` parameter.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag' ) ); ?>
```